# Does Typescript allow spread operator in type definition of objects or interfaces?

Tags: typescript

Note: this question is strictly regarding the spread operator in definition of the `type` itself. As an example consider the example below where the `Point3D` is defined using spread syntax, but the editor displays an error.

```
type Point = {x: number, y: number};
type Point3D = {...Point, z: number}; // Error
type Point3DAlt = Point & {z: number}; // Okay
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the spread operator.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense why the editor/compiler was not happy with that line.

Comment: @user3330840 you can use spread operator only with tuples data structure. See example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBGANAJjQZgLoChRIoAhBZAOipjSgBY0BWXKAeleXSiym1oajMgA